# If the set $S$ consists of $900,000,000$ whole numbers, each with the same number of digits, how many digits are the numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm learning College Algebra myself. I have a topic as the following:
The set, S consists of 900,000,000 whole numbers, each being the same number of digits long. How many digits long is a number from S? (Hint: use the fact that a whole number cannot start with the digit 0.)

But I don't really understand "each being the same number of digits long". May anyone help me explain this part? I'll find the answer myself then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you clarify what is a whole number? Perhaps an integer? I know because in Russian integer numbers literally translate as "whole"

Comment: Hi there. Whole number is natural number like 1,2,3,... except 0.

Comment: The same number of digits long means that all of the numbers have the same number of digits.  For instance, they could all have five digits such as $12345$, $27843$, and $30000$.

Comment: I think what is meant in the problem that all numbers in the set have the same number of digits. like 100 has 3 digits and 5432 has 4 digits. Also, if it is a set, all numbers in it should be different. That means, that all numbers have to have at least 900,000,000 digits. If it was smaller, it would not have been possible for them to be different. But it could also be larger than that

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you copied the question to the letter, it is a bad question. Did you change the phrasing or leave anything out?

Let's do a bit of a smaller example. Suppose that the number was 90 rather than 900,000,000. Then you will note that the 90 numbers
$$
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, \ldots, 97, 98, 99
$$
all have exactly 2 digits. So if your set consists of these 90 numbers, then the correct answer is 2. This is also presumably the intended answer to the question (at least if you replace 900,000,000 with 90).

(Note that the numbers "$01, 02, 03, \ldots, 09$" don't count: for the purposes of this question, numbers do not have leading zeroes, so these numbers should be written "$1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9$" and therefore have 1 digit, not 2.)

However, the 90 numbers
$$
110, 111, 112, \ldots, 197, 198, 199
$$
all have exactly 3 digits. So your set could consist of these 90 numbers as well, and then the answer would be 3. Because the question (as you wrote it) doesn't specify that the set $S$ should contain *all* numbers with that number of digits. If you add that condition, then the answer to the modified question is unequivocally 2.

Can you do the question for the number 900,000,000 (instead of 90) yourself?

Comment: Firstly, thank all of you, nice people! I understood the problem. Here how i solve it using Multiplication Principal:                                                                                                   - first digit takes 1 -> 9. From the second digit on, they take 0 -> 9. So I have equation:                                                                                                                                
    9x10^n = 900 000 000  <=>  n = 8                                                                                 => a number from S has (8+1) digits

Comment: @Willy, that's exactly right!